# Algorithm Time and Space Complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, return, time-complexity, space-complexity

It is a Textbook Assignment question in my Sophomore

Tried solving it for 3 days but having a hard time.

The question is:

**Find the Time and Space complexity , along with the Value Returned and No of function calls**

```
rec(n)
{
    if( n <= 2 )
        return 1;

    return 2*rec(sqrt(n)) + 2*rec(sqrt(n)) + log(n);
}
```

I got TC as **Θ(Logn)**, value returned as **Θ(log^2(n))**, number of function calls as **Θ(LogLogn)** and space complexity as **Θ(LogLogn)**

can anyone please help.

what is wrong and what's the right way if I am wrong!

Original problem statement @ https://ibb.co/Z8SvHcf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence relation describing the problem is:

```
 T(n) = 2T(√n) + logn
```

Now we define `S(n) = T(e^n)`
And we get:

```
S(n) = T(e^n) = 2T(√(e^n)) + log(e^n) = 2T(e^(n/2)) + n = 2S(n/2) + n
```

After applying master theorem we get:

```
S(n) = Θ(nlogn)
```

For `n > 0` we have

```
T(n) = S(logn) = Θ(lognloglogn)
```

You will find a more in-depth discussion here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96422/how-to-solve-tn-2t%E2%88%9Anlog-n-with-the-master-theorem?newreg=0deef64b56714962a0cd046f7f0ca745
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot :-) can you also please help me about knowing the space complexity , yes i got the time complexity , you explained well . But the Remaining 3 the space complexity , return value and the number of function calls

Comment: I guess (I AM NOT SURE) that the space complexity will be O(loglog(n)). Let's suppose that n = 4, then we have 1 function call hence the stack will contain 1 frame which is equal to loglog(4). When n = 16 we have 2 stack frames which is also equal to loglog(16) and the pattern continues.. someone right me if i am wrong.....

Comment: regrading the return value, iam not quite sure...